# Why can i not move individual Vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices

I'm trying to complete the make a donut in blender tutorial, but i am unable to select my vertices
Image is attatched
[image]

Comment: You are in face select mode. You can tell by the selection squares in the top left corner (next to where it says edit mode). Press 1 to go to vertex select or pick the box on the very left. If you are talking about not being able to select the donut, it is because it is a separate object. Switch from edit mode back to object mode (tab), select the donut, and then enter edit mode again (tab again).

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!